# If $U\sim U(-1,1)$ and $N\sim N(0,1)$ are independent, can we say that $U$ and $UN$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $U\sim U(-1,1)$,(uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$) and $N\sim N(0,1)$, (normal distribution with mean $0$, variance $1$(are independent, can we say that $U$ and $UN$ are independent?

I think they are not independent since conditional on $U$ just gives one direction of $N$, I mean positive or negative $N$ depends on U, but unconditional on $U$ has two possibility that N to be positive or negative, So I think they are unconditional, but I'm not sure how to prove it using rigorous equations.

Is there any rigorous proof of Independence of $U$ and $UN$?

Comment: They are not independent, since the conditional distribution of $UN$ given $U$ depends on the value of $U$. For example, $$\mathbf{Var}(UN\mid U)=U^2$$ depends on $U$.

Comment: If $U$ and $N$ are independent r.v.'s (with finite moments of order $4$) then $U$ and $UN$ CANNOT be independent unless $U$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If $N$ has a standard normal distribution and $X$ is independent of $N$, then $\mathbb E[g(X,N)\mid X]=v(X)$ with $v(x)=\mathbb E[g(x,N)]$. In particular, with $g(x,y)=e^{itxy}$, using the fact that the characteristic function of a standard normal distribution is $e^{-t^2/2}$, we get that
$$
\mathbb E\left[e^{itXN}\mid X\right]=\exp\left(-\frac{t^2X^2}2\right).
$$
If $X^2$ is not constant, then we cannot have independence between $X$ and $XN$.

In particular, if $U$ follows a uniform law on $[-1,1]$ (or any interval), the random variables $U$ and $UN$ are not independent.